# Solution for $e^{Ax}(x^2+Bx+C)=D$?

Tags: functions

Is there a neat solution (for $x$) to the following?

$A$, $B$, and $C$ are all real coefficients.

$$e^{Ax}(x^2+Bx+C)=D$$

Comment: Are you solving for $x$?

Comment: Yes, solving for x

Comment: Sorry - original question had an error in it. This has been fixed above.

Comment: Can only be solved numerically, no closed form solution exists.

Comment: In general, there's unlikely to be an analytic solution. You might be able to express it in terms of the Lambert W function

Comment: Also you need constraints on the coefficients because there is no solution for $ A = B = 0$, $C \ge 0$ and $D < 0$.

Comment: OK - that's all I really needed to know. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only if $(x^2+Bx+C)=(x+E)^2$ is a perfect square, that is to say if $B^2=4C$, $E=\frac12B$ you would have analytical solutions in terms of Lambert function.

If this was the case, solving $$e^{Ax}\left(x+E\right)^2=D$$ would lead to
$$x=-E+\frac 2A\, W\left(\pm\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{A^2 D\, e^{A E}}\right)$$ as for any equation which can write $$A+Bx+C\log(D+E x)=0$$
If this is not the case, only numerical methods could be used.